# Deletion of SQL Service Broker queue is slow

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-broker

We have a system using SQL server service broker inside a single database.
This database is mirrored using high-safety mode and a witness.

We have a routing application that receives messages from a queue and forward those messages to a node's queue.
On every 8 nodes we have another application that receives that message, process it and send back the status to the routing queue.

For some unknown reason, that application did not see that her queue was already present in the system and re-created that queue again and again. Now I have 20000 queues and 20000 associated service in the system instead of 8.

I started to delete them but it is really slow (+/- 3 minutes to delete 50 queues). Is this normally so slow ? Does the mirroring interfere with SSB ? Is there another method to delete all those queues ?

Thanks

Comment: Are there messages in the queue you are up to delete?